# Adding custom QWidget during runtime

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qwidget

I'm trying to implement a custom widget hierarchy:
 `QMainWindow` -> `QFrame` -> `MyWidget` -> `QFrame` -> `MySubWidget`

Here is how MyWidget class looks like:

```
    class MyWidget : public QWidget {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0, ...);
        ...
    public slots:
        void SlotFunction(int i);
        ...
    private:
        MySubWidget *sub_w;
        QFrame *sub_frame;
        ...
    }
```

If I try to create an MySubWidget during MyWidget constructor, then all MySubWidget elements are shown as intended:

```
    MyWidget::MyWidget (...) : QWidget(parent) {
        ...
        sub_frame = new QFrame(this);
        ...
        sub_w = new MySubWidget(sub_frame); // commented out on a runtime test
    }
```

But if I try to add subwidget during runtime, sub_frame remains blank. I.e. signal reaction:

```
    void MyWidget::SlotFunction(int i) {
        sub_w = new MySubWidget(sub_frame); // update, repaint, show and hide methods aren't helphul
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was having a very similar issue and it turned out to be a lack of call to the QWidget::show(). Perhaps that was your problem as well?

My question here: [Dynamically add instance inherited from QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575988/dynamically-add-instance-inherited-from-qwidget)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reaching your function?

At the top of your function before making a `new` instance of `MySubWidget` put:

```
qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
```

Is the slot connected properly?

Qt will let you know if it is unable to connect a slot using a runtime warning.  Look at the debug output that shows up in Qt Creator and it may mention a reason why the slot was never reached.

Is `subframe` visible?

If the parent of your object isn't visible, then showing or hiding the child object will only affect it when the parent is shown.

Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. I _multi_checked slot connection before asking and all frames are visible.